# jQuery hide next element by location on dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through some results and I would like a hide button to hide some extra information e.g. date! Each result will have the same class and Id names I need to make it so if the user clicks the anchor above the date it uses the next date in dom order.

```
@foreach ($statuses as $status)
    <h1>{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</h1>
    <a class="hide-date" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> Hide</a>
    <span class="date">{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
@endforeach

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide-date").click(function(){
        $(".date").hide();
    });
});
```

**Case 2**

```
    @foreach ($statuses as $status)
<div class="content">
    <div class="top-wrapper">
        <h1>{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</h1>
        <a class="hide-date" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> Hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        <span class="date">{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans() }</span>
    </div>
</div>
    @endforeach
```

At the moment it hides all of dates

Comment: no two elements can have same Id in a DOM. Violation of HTML rules

Comment: You're right sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

span `.date` is next sibling of clicked `.hide-date` element. you can use `.next()` to target it along with clicked element context `this`:

```
$(".hide-date").click(function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

**Solution for case 2:**

```
 $(".hide-date").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.date').hide();
});
```

Comment: Aha thanks that solved this issue. But what if it wasn't a child, and the H1 & span were in different divs? Or should I open up a new question for that one

Comment: @user1910046: Tha is the good practice actually. if you share that dom,  can share the solution as well.

Comment: Okay updated with a similar dom but split div's thanks

Comment: @user1910046: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide-date").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".date").hide();
    });
});
```

I sometimes do it like this, if I want to change order later on. [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) also works.

It's also a good practice to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide-date").on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".date").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not going to work because each set of `<h1>,a,span` are not wrapped in parent container

Comment: In that case, siblings would work. Either way, they would be wrapped in the <body> block, right?

Comment: yes but it will also have other set of  `.date` as sibling as well. you will need to target only relevant sibling

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide-date").click(function(){
       $(this).next(".date").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: do not encourage people to violate html rules.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar And how am I doing it ?

Comment: You used `.next("#date")` earlier.

Comment: The author added it first as ID. and please read my comment below the question !!!

Comment: yes if added as id, the rules are violated. and so did your earlier suggested solution